# Can't autowire WebTestClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to inject a WebTestClient in order to realize some integration tests using Spring Webflux.

I have to load a redis embedded software that I run with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class EmbeddedRedisConfiguration {

    private RedisServer redisServer;

    public EmbeddedRedisConfiguration(@Value("${spring.redis.port}") int redisPort) {
        this.redisServer = new RedisServer(redisPort);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        redisServer.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        redisServer.stop();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Foo> redisOperations(@Qualifier("redissonConnectionFactory") ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory factory) {

        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Foo> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Foo.class);
        RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Foo> builder = RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext(new StringRedisSerializer());
        RedisSerializationContext<String, Foo> context = builder.value(serializer).build();

        return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(factory, context);
    }
}
```

Running this class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class FooControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
          // do something
    }
}
```

i receive this error:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

If I change this line

```
@SpringBootTest
```

to this line

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

The WebTestClient is available for autowiring, but the application bootstraps before my test profile configuration, failing to connect to embedded redis:

```
Factory method 'redisson' threw exception; nested exception is org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis server: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379
```

There is a way to inject WebTestClient without bring up the webenvironment or a way to load my embedded redis config before other things?

**Edit**

It seems that the problem is that `RedissonAutoConfiguration` is loaded

Comment: several things, when not using webEnvironment it defaults to `WebEnvironment.MOCK` so it doesn't start a full server. But you need to use `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` to configure and autowire the testclient